# Convert an image of a signal into a python list - by specifying no of points in 1D

Tags: python, image, numpy, process

I'm struggling to convert an image of a signal back to a python list (it was plotted a long time ago and I have lost the data I have only the images). 
I've searched on the internet but I find answers about how to convert a 2d image into a 1d and I want to get the signal back.

Long story short:
I have this image of a signal:

[image]

and I want to convert this to a python list with a size of 65535 so my list should be looking like this:
list = [0.14, 0.144, 0.12 ...... ]

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know the first y value is 0.14? And what is the y value of the peak?

Comment: let's say from a percentage 0-100 where 0 means the left down corner pixel and 100 means left up corner pixel

Comment: Load the image into a 2d data structure that you can scan each *row* and look for non-white pixels; record/capture/keep the row/col value for each non-white pixel - rows equal amplitude and columns equal time .If you don't need the time just discard it.

Comment: @MarkSetchellMar thanks for your support and for all others support. Yep, it kind of worked the problem was that I did not have the same sample rate as original (having  3000 data points or 5000 or it depends) (which was not a surprise). 
I've used your solution and it worked as a quick demo to train a small CNN but in the end, I had to find the old database and implement again the code!
Thanks, StackOverflow community! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first plan, you could load the image using PIL/Pillow, or OpenCV, greyscale it and resize it to 65536 pixels wide by 100 pixels tall.

Then you will have a Numpy array with dimensions (100,65536). You can then run `np.argmin()` to find the index (y-value) of the darkest pixel in each column.

Or, find the indices of all the low valued pixels and take their median instead of the second step above.

The code starts off like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image and convert to greyscale
im = Image.open('signal.png').convert('L')

# Resize to match required output
big = im.resize((65536,100), resample=Image.NEAREST)

# Make Numpy array
na = np.array(big)

# This looks about right, I think
print(np.argmin(na,axis=0))
```

If you trim the image so that the signal touches the edges all the way around, then the first black pixel on the left comes out as list element 0, the last pixel on the right comes out as the last element of your list and the lowest black pixel comes out with y-value of 0 and the peak comes out with y-value of 100.

Trimming would look like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Load image and convert to greyscale
im = Image.open('signal.png').convert('L') 

# Get bounding box
bbox = ImageOps.invert(im).getbbox() 

# Trim original image so that signal touches edge on all sides
im = im.crop(bbox)

... continue as before ...
```

Comment: Nice. With PIL/Pillow creates inverted image. .. `sig = np.abs(100-np.argmin(na,axis=0)`

Comment: @wwii Yes, thank you - the coordinates start at top-left with PIL.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you'll have to "scan" the images left to right and identify the correct signal value at each "time step." As the image you presented doesn't have scale / units, you'll probably want to normalize all signal values from 0 to 1, as you've implied in your answer. Later you can adjust the scale of the signal if that's not the right range.

It looks like your images have some anti-aliasing at each step of the signal, which means that you won't have columns of all zeros except for one "signal" value. You'll have a cluster of signal values at each time step, some of which are weaker, because the image compression has blurred the signal slightly. This shouldn't be a problem, since you'll just find the max at each time step.

Assuming these images are in grayscale (if not, convert to grayscale), you'd want to find the maximum (or minimum, if the signal is drawn in black) color value at each column of pixels in the images (representing timesteps of the signal).

Mark Setchell's suggestion of PIL/Pillow seems like a great first step.

numpy's [amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) takes a matrix and flattens it to the max across an entire axis.